# Aside from brute force, how can I solve this puzzle?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, mathematics, word-problem

> Once upon a time, and old lady went to sell her vast quantity of eggs at the local market. When asked how many she had, she replied:
>
> Son, I can't count past 100 but I know that:
>
> If you divide the number of eggs by 2 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 3 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 4 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 5 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 6 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 7 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 8 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 9 there will be one egg left.
>   If you divide the number of eggs by 10 there will be one egg left.
>
> Finally. If you divide the number of eggs by 11 there will be NO EGGS left!
>
> How many eggs did the old lady have?

Source (with solution): [BrainBashers](http://www.brainbashers.com/showanswer.asp?ref=ZFMU)

From reading the puzzle, some easily-indentifiable properties of the total number of eggs are:

- it's a multiple of 11 (remainder of 0 if divided by 11)
- it's odd (if divided by 2 there's one egg remaining)

I haven't been able to come up with any other clues, so the only way I can see to solve this puzzle is to brute-force it (that is, start listing odd multiples of 11 and manually check if `x modulo 3->10 = 1`.

```
11, 33, 55, 77, 99, 121, 143...
```

At this point I got bored of brute-forcing it and decided there had to be a better way.

Is there? Can I use the other clues to build more rules to make it easier to find the correct number? (I started to think that maybe combining two clues would lead to a nugget of information, but then I couldn't figure out how to do that.) What math can I use to solve this other than brute-forcing the set of odd multiples of 11?

Comment: 25201 is the answer. http://www.brainbashers.com/showanswer.asp?ref=ZFMU

Comment: The link you gave didn't turn up the same puzzle for me. But Google found a permalink, and there is a solution there (which is largely what I wrote, but less clear IMO and not completely correct).

Comment: I found a suitable answer really quickly with just 10!+1

Comment: This is a version of the chinese remainder theorem problem. Take a look here for a general solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: @KBusc: That page seems to suggest that all of the divisors need to be pairwise coprime. Did I miss something in there that generalises it to non-coprime or is there a way to reduce this problem trivially to one of coprimes?

Comment: She couldn't count past 100 yet she had 25201 eggs? Did she have a chicken farm or something?

Answer (score 59):

Remove one egg. Now the number of eggs is divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Therefore it is divisible by their [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). There are algorithms to compute the LCM; for example you can write the prime factor decompositions and take the maximum for each factor. Here the result is 7*5*9*8 = 2520. So the original number of eggs is of the form 2520*x+1.

2520 divided by 11 is 229 with a remainder of 1. The successive values of the remainder of 2520*x+1 modulo 11 for x=1,2,3,… are 1+1, 2+1, 3+1, … so x=10 gives the smallest possible number of eggs: 2520*10+1 = 25201.

25201 is not the only answer: if you add 11 to x, you get another answer. The set of possible answers are all the numbers of the form 2520*(11*y+10)+1, i.e. 25201 plus any multiple of 27720.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the LCM of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 is 8*9*5*7=2520.

Comment: @Arthur: Indeed it is. It's just a simple prime factorization after all: `2*2*2*3*3*5*7 = 2520`. For the remainder of the solution we just need to solve `2520x + 1 mod 11 = 0` using modular math if we don't just want to try different x's until one works.

Comment: @ArthurFischer That teaches me not to write it out or check it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, this makes the statement "I can't count past 100" irrelevant, I was expecting that that statement limits the result to be below 100. Anyway, +1!

Comment: @justhalf I think it means the exact opposite, that the answer must be greater than 100.  He can't count past 100, BUT he knows these other facts.

Answer (score 18):

Gilles certainly has the right idea, find the LCM of 2..10, +1. To take it a but further, here's the method I find easiest to find the LCM of relatively low (and/or easy-to-factor) numbers.

First, find the prime factors of all the numbers:

| number | factors |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2, 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 2, 3 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 2, 2, 2 |
| 9 | 3, 3 |
| 10 | 2, 5 |

Now go through that list and find the highest count of each factor in any of the numbers. It may be easiest to make a table

| number | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | 3 |  |  |
| 4 | 2, 2 |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  | 5 |  |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  | 7 |
| 8 | 2, 2, 2 |  |  |  |
| 9 |  | 3, 3 |  |  |
| 10 | 2 |  | 5 |  |
| max | 2,2,2 | 3,3 | 5 | 7 |

Now just multiply all the numbers in the $max$ row and you have your number. If you rearrange and combine numbers in the right way it might be easier to multiply out in your head.

$$2\times2\times2\times3\times3\times5\times7 = 7\times9\times4\times10 = 63\times4\times10 = 2520$$

So we need to find a number of the form $2520\times k+1 \equiv 0\mod11$.  Since $2520 \equiv 1 \mod 11$, we want the smallest $k$ such that $1\times k + 1 \equiv 0\mod11$. Conveniently, we can easily see that that will be $k = 10$, for a final answer of $25201$.

Comment: May I also suggest adding the general solution $\forall\ n \in N: 2520 \times (11n + 10) + 1$? I mean sure it's obvious to you or me, but I'm not sure how common congruent math is in math classes.
'

Answer (score 8):

As shown in Gilles' answer and others, it is straightforward to find answer E by noticing that E is divisible by 11, and E-1 is divisible by each of 2 through 10, hence by the LCM of 2 through 10, or 2520.

If the remainders were not all 1, a more-general approach would be needed.  The  *Chinese remainder theorem* (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)) is good for such problems.  The calculations below show an application of the [constructive algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#A_constructive_algorithm_to_find_the_solution) given in the Wikipedia article.

First, the method applies to pairwise coprime integers.  For the present problem, we can work with 11, 9, 8, 7, 5 and ignore the other numbers because if the remainder is 1 when dividing by 8, then it's 1 when dividing by 4 or by 2; similarly for 9 vs 3.  If it's 1 when dividing by 2 or 5, then it's 1 when dividing by 10; similarly for 2 and 3 vs 6.  So it's adequate to work with {11, 9, 8, 7, 5}, members of which are pairwise coprime.

Next, N = 11·9·8·7·5 = 27720; and dividing N by members of {11, 9, 8, 7, 5} gives {2520, 3080, 3465, 3960, 5544}.

Now we apply the extended Euclidean algorithm to each nᵢ, N/nᵢ pair and obtain:

```
gcd 11, 2520 = 1 =  -229 * 11 +  1 * 2520
gcd  9, 3080 = 1 =  1369 *  9 + -4 * 3080
gcd  8, 3465 = 1 =  -433 *  8 +  1 * 3465
gcd  7, 3960 = 1 = -1697 *  7 +  3 * 3960
gcd  5, 5544 = 1 =  1109 *  5 + -1 * 5544
```

The products at the right are eᵢ; as a set, {2520, -12320, 3465, 11880, -5544}.  Now we compute x = Σ(aᵢ·eᵢ) where the aᵢ are from the set of desired remainders, {0,1,1,1,1} for respective members of {11, 9, 8, 7, 5}.  That is, x = 0*2520-12320+3465+11880-5544 = -2519, and we find that -2519 is indeed a solution, although negative.

At this point, we have -2519 as a result of applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem; now we need to observe that adding the LCM of {11, 9, 8, 7, 5}, or 27720, produces another solution, giving us the solution -2519+27720 = 25201, the same as mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 7):

What do we know about your numbers?

Well it's 1 greater than a multiple of 2.
1 greater than a multiple of 3.
1 greater than a multiple of 4.
...
1 greater than a multiple of 10.
a multiple of 11.

The first 9 properties are easy. `10! + 1` will cover that. The only question is, is it divisible by 11? Well, a quick check with a calculator reveals that it is.

therefore 3628801 is a possible answer.

The question doesn't seem to ask for the smallest solution, and in fact this puzzle has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Actually, by Wilson's Theorem, n! + 1 will always be divisible by n+1 when n+1 is prime, so it's not necessary to check explicitly.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Cool! Learn something new every day! After seeing that it was divisible by 11, I was wondering if it worked in general. Tried it for 11!+1 and it wasn't divisible by 12 and stopped there. I didn't consider that the primality would be that important here. Thank you

Comment: @ArthurFischer After reading a little bit on the theorem, it appears to go both ways actually. If n+1 is prime, then n!+1 is divisible by n+1. But also that if n!+1 is divisible by n+1, then n+1 is prime.

Comment: Actually, you can check that 10!+1 is a multiple of 11 explicitly on a calculator.  So it is not necessary to invoke Wilson's Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Least Common Multiple of all the numbers from 2 to 10, inclusive, which is 2520, then add 1, which would be 2521. Then take 2521 mod 11, which is congruent to 2 mod 11. Then you add another 2520, and take 5041 mod 11, which is congruent to 3 mod 11. Noticing that it increases by 1 mod 11 each time, and since you want 0 mod 11, or 11 mod 11, you'll need to add $2520*8$ to 5041, which gives us the desired $25201$.

By the way, 25201 eggs will weigh over 3000 pounds!!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for constructing such a number (x):

- X mod 10 = 1: This means that the ones digit of X is 1.
- X mod 9 = 1: This means that the sum of all of the digits except the ones digit is 9.  I know this because the sum of the digits of all numbers divisible by 9 is 9 (549 -> 5 + 4 + 9 = 18 -> 1 + 8 = 9)
- X mod 4 = 1: This is important because numbers divisible by 4 have a property that the last two digits of the number are divisible by 4.  (I know that 46382648462984624 is divisible by 4 because the last two digits, 24, are divisible by four)

  - Let's look at what this means.  Take the number 331.  Subtract 1 to get 330.  The last two digits of 330 are not divisible by 4, therefore X <> 331.  In fact we can say that the last two digits of X cannot be 31.  So X <> 531, and X <> 75873631, you get the idea.
  - From the previous point, you can see that the last two digits of X must be one of { 01, 21, 41, 61, and 81 }

This should narrow down your search space.  Let's try some numbers:

- 110: While divisible by 11, the ones digit is not 1, the digits don't sum to 10, and 09 is not divisible by 4.  X <> 110
- 121: The ones digit is 1, but the digits don't sum to 10, and 20 is not divisible by 4.  X <> 121:
- 281: The ones digit is 1, the digits sum to 10, and 80 is divisible by 4.  X is a candidate.

Now you just have to check is 281 is divisible by 11, and that 280 is divisible by 8, 7, and 6.  You know it's divisible 5 because it's divisible by 10.  Same thing for 4 -> 8, 3 -> 9, and 2 -> 8.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}
LLCM(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)&=2\times3\times2\times5\times7\times2\times3\\
&=2520\end{array}$$
Let $x+1$ be the solution
And $x,n,k\in\mathbb{N}$
$$x\equiv0\mod2520$$
$$x=2520n$$
$$x+1\equiv0\mod11$$
$$2520n+1\equiv0\mod11$$
$$2520n\equiv10\mod11$$
$$2520\equiv1\mod11$$
$$n\equiv10\mod11$$
$$n=11k+10$$
$$x+1=2520(11k+10)+1$$

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Probably because this question has been answered multiple times before, and there is no point for another answer.